# MongoDB querying with Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to build mongoDB query based on python's dictionaries.
The problem that a key should be unique in dicts.
See the example

MongoDB data:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4dcd3ebc9278000000005158"),
        col1 : 'foo'
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4dcd3ebc9278000000005159"),
        col1 : 'bar'
}
```

Python code:

```
dict = {'col1': 'foo'}
dict.update({'col1': 'bar'})

db.test.find(dict)
```

shows only one line with `col1=='bar'`

```
>>> dict
{'col1': 'bar'}
```

How can I build the right MongoDB query using dictionaries (or anything) which does not need to have unique keys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for documents where 'col1' is either 'foo' OR 'bar'?

If so, then you want `db.test.find({'col1': {'$in': ['foo', 'bar']}});`

To explain, that query matches documents where the value of `col1` is `in` the list `['foo', 'bar']`.

Advanced mongodb queries are documented here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution for you is just a simple way, you should push each object in a dict and store them in an array:

```
dict = []
your_obj = {'col1': 'foo'}
dict.append(your_obj)
dict.append({'col1': 'bar'})
for o in dict:
    db.test.find(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be to use the `$exists` operator in mongodb.

```py
query = {'col1': {'$exists': 'true'}}
db.test.find(dict)
```

This way you would not have to specify what values *col1* could take.